# Cakephp 2.3 $this->Auth->allow() is not working as expected

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to use the AuthComponent in CakePHP 2.3 but it's not behaving the way I would expect it to.

Basically, when I do

$this->Auth->allow('view');

The user is only supposed to have access to the view method, which is what is happening so great.

The problem is, when the user logs in, he suddenly has access to the 'add' method as well (my only other method in the controller at the moment. When he logs out, he doesn't have access to add anymore.

Here's my code:

//AppController

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Blowfish' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')
            )
        )
    )

);

public function beforeFilter() {      
  $this->Auth->deny('add');
  $this->Auth->allow('view');
}

}
```

My PagesController is simply this:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class PagesController extends AppController {

public $uses = array('Pages');

public function view($id = null) {
       echo 'In view';
    }

public function add($id = null) {
       echo 'In add';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what allow()/deny() do. They are meant specify whether an action can be accessed with or without authentication (aka login). It's not meant to control authorization i.e. control access to action after a user is logged in. For that purpose you to configure authorization. Reading [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) should help you better understand.

Comment: Thank you sir. That's what I was worried about. I'm assuming that isAuthorized will only work with people who have accounts then?

Comment: Yes `isAuthorized` is used for authorization and comes into play only after a user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

if you work on cakephp 2.x you must do like this :

```
function beforeFilter(){       
    $this->Auth->allow(array('action you want to allow1','action you want to allow2'));
}
```

- allow(array()) instead allow()

---put that code into controller have action you want allow access without login

if you use $this->Auth->allow() you must call parent::beforeFilter(); in function beforeFilter() like this :

```
function beforeFilter(){     
             parent::beforeFilter();    
    $this->Auth->allow('add','view');
}
```